# Encrypt and Decrypt object

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a class of two strings

I want to decrypt and encrypt using RC4 , I know how to do that for one string

http://tofuculture.com/blog/post/RC4-Encryption-in-C.aspx

can I apply to whole object

Comment: Do you want the output to be a single string or multiple strings? All you need to do in the former case is concatenate the two values (with a separation character if you are afraid of duplication)

Comment: I want to custom serialize for the whole object

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to serialize into a complex format is to first serialize into a simple format (in this case string) and then perform the known transformation from the simple to complex.

So in your example you want to serialize two strings, so decide on a separation character or string that won't appear in your data and use it to separate the two strings. This allows you to create a single string, which you already know how to handle. Then when you want to deserialize you do the opposite, finding the separation and splitting the strings again into a new object.